# Como posso fazer o tratamento dos Interops com um AssemblyResolve para um projecto do tipo Class Library (DLL)

Tags: .net

Este exemplo é dum projecto Windows Forms que funciona correctamente.

```
namespace PriDebug_v9
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
            Application.Run(new Debug());
        }

        public static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            string assemblyFullName;

            System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyName;

            const string PRIMAVERA_COMMON_FILES_FOLDER = "PRIMAVERA\\SG900";

            assemblyName = new System.Reflection.AssemblyName(args.Name);

            assemblyFullName = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFilesX86), PRIMAVERA_COMMON_FILES_FOLDER, assemblyName.Name + ".DLL");

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(assemblyFullName))
            {
                return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyFullName);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O processo é exatamente o mesmo, mas como numa `Class Library` não tem método de entrada (`Main`), terá que colocar o `Assembly Resolve` no construtor da classe (exemplo completo):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MyClassLibrary
{
    using static Environment.SpecialFolder;

    public class MyClass
    {
        const string PRIMAVERA_COMMON_FILES_FOLDER = @"PRIMAVERA\SG900";

        public MyClass() => AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyResolve;

        private Assembly AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            string assemblyFullName;
            AssemblyName assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);

            assemblyFullName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(CommonProgramFilesX86), PRIMAVERA_COMMON_FILES_FOLDER, assemblyName.Name + ".DLL");

            if (File.Exists(assemblyFullName))
                return Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyFullName);
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Caro José

À resposta do João que está correta , apenas acrescento que na realidade de integração com o ERP V10 existe um artigo no developers Network que explica justamente com todos os detalhes (C# e VB.net) como tratar dessa questão.

Veja o artigo [aqui](https://developers.primaverabss.com/v10/criar-assembly-resolver/)

Comment: Obrigado Sérgio, este caso em particular é para um projecto da versão 9. Já testei e não dá nenhum erro. Estava a tentar "forçar" o erro, para ter 100% a certeza que estava tudo correcto.

Comment: Olá @JoséMiguelFerreira. Marque as respostas como úteis e/ou corretas. Veja [Porque é importante votar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).